# How to use the PEAR Mail package to sent mail by php?

Tags: php, email

How to use PHP Pear Mail to sent mail. I'm using the following code in demo.php file:

```
$options = array();


//Setting for configration of mail server SMTP
$options['host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$options['port'] = '465';
$options['auth'] = true;
$options['username'] = 'username@gmail.com';
$options['password'] = 'mypassword';

$mailer = Mail::factory('smtp',$options);

$headers = array();

$headers['From'] = 'username@gmail.com';
$headers['To']   = 'recipiet@gmail.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Learn sent mail with php';

//List of recipiets
$recipiet= 'recipiets@gmail.com';

$body = '<b>I love you</b>';


//Sent mail
$result = $mailer->send($recipiet,$headers,$body);

if(PEAR::isError($result)){
    $error = $result->getMessage();
    echo htmlspecialchars($error);
}
```

But it's show **authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y184sm509718pfg.94 - gsmtp)]**
Help me!!!